# Yup Date Validation with Formik - Cannot Be Today nor a Historic Date

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

**Use Case:** Ensure the job posting start date is not today, nor a date in the past.

**My code is:**

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
    startDate: yup.string().required("Please complete this field.").nullable(),
})
```

**Question:** How do I ensure it is neither today, nor a historic date?

Side note, I am using formik, with the `validationSchema` used as below:

```
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit,
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is as follows:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
    startDate: yup
      .date()
      .min(new Date(), "ERROR MESSAGE")
      .required("Please complete this field.")
      .nullable(),
})
```